# Operand type mismatch for cmov

Tags: assembly, att

I can't seem to get `cmove` to work the way I want it to. I have this bit of code:

```
cmove   $1, %eax
```

And I get this error on compilation:

```
Error: operand type mismatch for `cmove'
```

However, replacing `cmove` with, say, `mov` works perfectly, and

```
mov    $1,   %ecx
cmove  %ecx, %eax
```

works too. I've tried to use `cmovel` as well, but it just doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Using `cmov` instructions effectively inevitably means that you'll have to clobber a scratch register. Your second snippet is the way you do this, using `ecx` as the scratch register. Note how well this works since the `mov` instruction never affects the flags, so you can always insert it in-between the test (which sets the flags) and the conditional-move.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

For `cmove $1,%eax` to work there'd have to be a form of `cmove` that accepts `r32,imm` (or `r/m32,imm`) as an argument combination. But the only valid forms of `cmove` listed in [Intel's manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) are:

```
CMOVE r16, r/m16
CMOVE r32, r/m32
CMOVE r64, r/m64
```

In the description for `CMOVcc` they spell this out:

> These instructions can move 16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit values from memory to a general-purpose register or from one
>   general-purpose register to another.

Comment: So it's not that I'm doing something wrong, it just doesn't work that way... Oh well.